# Mojo::DOM HTML extraction

Tags: html, perl, mojo-dom

I'm trying to extract quite a bit of data from a perfectly structured web page and struggling with [`Mojo::DOM`](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) methods. I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

The truncated HTML with interesting data follows:

```
 <div class="post" data-story-id="3964117" data-visited="false">//extracting story-id
  <h2 class="post_title page_title"><a href="http://example.com/story/some_url" class="to-comments">header.</a></h2>
  //useless data and tags

<a href="http://example.com/story/some_url" class="b-story__show-all">
  <span>useless data</span>
</a>

<div class="post_tags">
  <ul>
    <li class="post_tag post_tag_strawberry hidden"><a href="http://example.com/search.php?n=32&r=3">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li class="post_tag"><a href="http://example.com/tag/tag1/hot">tag1</a></li>
    <li class="post_tag"><a href="http://example.com/tag/tag2/hot">tag2</a></li>
    <li class="post_tag"><a href="http://example.com/tag/tag1/hot">tag3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="post_actions_box">

  <div class="post_rating_box">
    <ul data-story-id="3964117" data-vote="0" data-can-vote="true">
      <li><span class="post_rating post_rating_up control">&nbsp;</span></li>
      <li><span class="post_rating_count control label">1956</span></li> //1956 - interesting value
      <li><span class="post_rating post_rating_down control">&nbsp;</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="post_more_box">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <span class="post_more control">&nbsp;</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="post_comments_count label to-comments" href="http://example.com/story/some_url#comments">132&nbsp;<i>&nbsp;</i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

What I have right now is

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Mojo::DOM;


my $file = "index2.html";
local( $/, *FH ) ;
open( FH, $file ) or die "sudden flaming death\n";
my $text = <FH>;
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new;
$dom->parse($text);
my $ids = $dom->find('div.post')
    ->each (sub {print $_->attr('data-story-id'), "\n";});
$dom->find('a.to-comments')->each (sub {print $_->text, "\n";});
```

This mess extracts `data-story-id` from the src and header value (tested the same with href value), but all my other attempts fail.

```
3964117
Header
132
```

"post_rating_count control label" is not extracted. I could get the first href values with searching for `a.to-comments` and returning `attr('href')`, but for some reason it also returnes me values of a link in the end of the segment with `class="post_comments_count label to-comments"`. The same happens with header value extraction.

In the final end I am looking for an array with data structure with following fields:

- story-id (this is is a success)
- href (somehow, matching more than needed.)
- header (somehow, matching more than needed.)
- list of tags as a string (no idea how to do that)

What is more, I feel it is possible to optimize the code and make it look a bit better, but my kung-fu is not so strong.

Comment: Your HTML isn't well-formed. You have a superfluous closing `</div>` tag, which makes me wonder whether you have removed an opening `<div>` tag in the *"useless content and html structures"*. Please can you fix it

Comment: yes, indeed, sorry about that. updated the code..

Comment: Thank you. Is there not a single element that encloses all the data for each post? In other words, does the next `<div class="post">` really follow on immediately after the `<div class="post_actions_box">`?

Comment: Just was in progress for testing. May I please ask you several questions in the "answer" section?

Comment: I'm not happy with my solution until you've resolved my doubts about the real content of the HTML, so can we fix that first? Stack Overflow is a *knowledge base* rather than a forum, so every entry is like a Wikipedia article and should be as correct as possible. I can create a chat room where we can talk, but I would like to know the nature of your questions first

Comment: your assumption is perfectly correct - the whole post is sitting inside of a<div class ="post" >, sorry for double confusion. my questions mostly  relate to Mojo methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102536/discussion-between-dvalin-swamp-and-borodin).

Comment: You should come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102535/mojodom) to talk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed as I said in my comment. I've guessed where the missing `<div>` might go but I'm probably wrong. I've assumed the last `</div>` in the data corresponds to the first `<div>`, so that the whole block constitutes a single post

The main problem you have is trying to do everything inside an `each` method call on your `Mojo::Collection` objects. It's far easier to use Perl to iterate of each collection, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;

use constant HTML_FILE => 'index2.html';

my $html = do {
    open my $fh, '<', HTML_FILE or die $!;
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

for my $post ( $dom->find('div.post')->each ) {

    printf "Post ID:     %s\n", $post->attr('data-story-id');

    my $anchor = $post->at('h2.post_title > a');
    printf "Post href:   %s\n", $anchor->attr('href');
    printf "Post header: %s\n", $anchor->text;

    my @tags = $post->find('li.post_tag > a')->map('text')->each;

    printf "Tags:        %s\n", join ', ', @tags;

    print "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
Post ID:     3964117
Post href:   http://example.com/story/some_url
Post header: Header
Tags:        some_value, tag1, tag2, tag3
```